# Pandas: enumerated lambda function with pd.merge unable to unpack tuple values

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a list of pandas dataframes stored as `dfs` and a small reduce function to perform inner merges along all the dataframes and renames the columns with appropriate suffixes, like so:

```
    reduced_df = reduce(lambda left, right:
               pd.merge(left[1], right[1], on='id', how='outer',
                        suffixes=[F"_{left[0]}", F"_{right[0]}"]).fillna(0, downcast='infer'), enumerate(dfs))
```

My traceback reads as follows:

[image]

And I get a KeyError 1 trace back to `pd.merge(left[1], right[1]`.

Interestingly, when I remove the enumerate(dfs) and just pass in the left/right frames after cleaning the suffix code, the function passes fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is work fine on my side , by only using `suffixes=[str(left[0]), str(right[0])]
`, I think your f-string is wrong

Comment: For me, swapping out the f-strings for str() converts still throws the pandas KeyError: 1